# passing id as a parameter to the actionlink in details view of the controller in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-5

I've been trying to use the details.cshtml view of the scaffolded controller to let users access their profile. To do that i'll need to pass the id(which is the primary key)  to the action link and with a click have user access their profile.

**Below is the code:**

```
<li>@Html.ActionLink("My Profile", "Details", "Techie", routeValues: new { @id = Model.ID }, htmlAttributes: new { })</li>
```

**The controller:**

```
public ActionResult Details(int? id)
{
    if (id == null)
    {
        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
    }

    Techie techie = db.Techie.Include(f => f.TechieFiles).SingleOrDefault(f => f.ID == id);

    if (techie == null)
    {
        return HttpNotFound();
    }
    return View(techie);
}
```

**and the model:**

```
public class Techie
{
    private DateTime _date = DateTime.UtcNow;
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "User Name")]
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "The email address is required")]
    [EmailAddress(ErrorMessage = "Oops! Seems you've entered an invalid Email Address")]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public Gender Sex { get; set; } 
    ...
}
```

**Running the project throws an error.
Exception Details: Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException: Cannot perform runtime binding on a null reference
Source Error:**

```
Line 68:                                             )*@
Line 69:                                         @*@model TechTalent.Models.Techie*@
Line 70:                                         @Html.ActionLink("My Profile", "Details", "Techie", routeValues: new { @id = Model.ID }, htmlAttributes: new { })
Line 71:                                     </li>
Line 72:                                     <li>

Source File: c:\Users\Spunk06\Desktop\Tech Talent\TechTalent 050717\TechTalent\Views\Shared\_Layout.cshtml    Line: 70
```

what do I need to do to make it work? Thanks in advance.

Comment: in your @Html.ActionLink("My Profile", "Details", "Techie", routeValues: new { @id = Model.ID }, htmlAttributes: new { }) what is this "Techie" is? Is it your controller name?

Comment: Yes, Techie  is the controller name. Below is the exception details  
 Exception Details: Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException: Cannot perform runtime binding on a null reference

Comment: You should use @Html.ActionLink and pass new {id = someID} that you want to pass. One more thing is that this line Techie techie = db.Techie.Include(f => f.TechieFiles).SingleOrDefault(f => f.ID == id); should be included in else block logically.

Comment: did you tried with the formatted action link provided by me?

Comment: @AmitMishra, if i run @HtmlActionLink("My Profile","Details","Techie", new{@id = 1}, null), it gets executed but what i want is a situation whereby the id is passed based on id of the techie in the Techie database.

Comment: yes and that id should be present on the view you're passing the request from. can you share the view code? if your view doesn't know anything about  the techie before passing on the request then before sending the request you need to capture the id and then use @Html.ActionLink.

Comment: did u tried with the modified action link?

Comment: @AmitMishra  **Here is the details view**                                                            
 `@model TechTalent.Models.Techie

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Details";
}

<div class="container-fluid" id="log" style="font-family: Verdana; font-size: 10px;">... with the @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Techie_Fields)</div>`

Comment: @uɐpuɐɥƆ yes i did, the exception is not different: Exception Details: Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException: Cannot perform runtime binding on a null reference

Comment: Have you actually used the ActionLink code on a page where the Model has an ID for a user?

Comment: @Morgan yes i did and it worked fine. My challenge now is using the actionlink to the details view as a navigation dropdown link for users to access their details.

Comment: The actionlink is in my _Layout.cshtml and when i check the references on the primary key column for the Techie model i.e `public class Techie { public int ID {get; set;} ...}`,  the  actionlink in the layout view is not being referenced.

Comment: @ChandanKumar yes i did and i got, it didn't hit the details action. what do i need to do next?

Answer (score 1):

**I actually got it to work. I set a relationship with AspNetUser Table and set the UserId from the table as my primary key(string).**

**My new Code: Details Action**

```
public ActionResult Details(string id)
{
    if (id == null)
    {
        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
    }

    Techie techie = db.Techie.Include(f => f.TechieFiles).SingleOrDefault(f => f.ApplicationUserID == id);

    if (techie == null)
    {
        return HttpNotFound();
    }
    return View(techie);
}
```

**and my ActionLink is**

```
<li>@Html.ActionLink("My Profile", "Details", "Techie", routeValues: new { @id = User.Identity.getUserId() }, htmlAttributes: new { })</li>
```

**Thank you.**